# Abstract subclass of abstract base class

Tags: c++, abstract-class

I have an abstract base class. Suppose, I want the derived class to also be abstract and leave the responsibility of implementation of the pure virtual functions to a further lower class. What is the best way of doing it?

```
class Animal {
public:
    virtual void makeNoise() = 0;
};

class Dog : public Animal {
};
```

Is it better to leave it blank like this, or should I do:

```
class Dog : public Animal {
public:
    virtual void makeNoise() = 0;

};
```

Or how about ignoring the virtual keyword and:

```
class Dog : public Animal {
public:
    void makeNoise() = 0;
};
```

What is the most suitable way of doing it?

Comment: Is the `Dog` class supposed to be an abstract class as well?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Yes.

Comment: Did someone say coupling?

Comment: You don't even have to write that in `class Dog`; the method will be inherited and will stay purely virtual.

Comment: @Fireho: Which is case-1 that I wrote. Thanks for your input.

Comment: You only need to repeat an interface if you are trying to change the protections on it that came from the base. Otherwise, any further derived is still required to provide an implementation. It is debatable whether repeating the interface improves readability.

Answer (score 2):

There is no functional difference between the different options (as you don't change the accessibility), but

- I'd prefer option one, as it avoids code duplication.
- Option 3 is the worst possibility, because - although it is obvious that a pure virtual function (indicated by `=0`) is virtual - it is less consistent with the declaration of other (pure) virtual functions introduced in `Dog`.
- I'd only revert to option 2 if

  - `Dog` is part of a library that you distribute to others
  - It introduces new pure virtual functions itself.
  - `Animal` itself is not supposed to be further used by the "typical user" directly

  That way, a client that derives from `Dog` has all necessary information about which functions he has to implement in one place.